# Fast slicing of dataframe/list/numpy array of tuples

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe where one column consists of tuples, i.e

```
df['A'].values = array([(1,2), (5,6), (11,12)])
```

Now I want to split this into two different columns. A working solution is

```
df['A1'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
```

But this is extremely slow. On my Dataframe it takes multiple minutes. So I would like to vectorize this, to something like

```
df['A1'] = df['A'][:,0]
```

With pandas, or using numpy or anything. But all of them give me an error similar to

"*** KeyError: 'key of type tuple not found and not a MultiIndex'"

Is there any vectorized way? This feels like a super simple question and task but i cannot find any working and properly vectorized function.

Answer (score 0):

```
n: int = 2

df = pd.DataFrame(df["A"].apply(lambda x: (x[:n], x[n:])).tolist(), index=df.index)
```

you can have a look into pandarallel also.

Answer (score 0):

I'll do it in numpy and skip over the pandas bits.

You can get a decent speedup using `np.fromiter` together with either `itertools.chain.from_iterable` to extract everything in one go or `operator.itemgetter` for individual columns.

```
import operator as op
import itertools as it

a = [*zip(range(10000),range(10000,20000))]
A = np.empty(10000,object)
A[...] = a
A
# array([(0, 10000), (1, 10001), (2, 10002), ..., (9997, 19997),
#        (9998, 19998), (9999, 19999)], dtype=object)

(*np.fromiter(it.chain.from_iterable(A),int,len(A[0])*A.size).reshape(A.size,-1).T,)
# (array([   0,    1,    2, ..., 9997, 9998, 9999]), array([10000, 10001,          
#     10002, ..., 19997, 19998, 19999]))
np.fromiter(map(op.itemgetter(0),A),int,A.size)
# array([   0,    1,    2, ..., 9997, 9998, 9999])
```